# Mongodb Number of Connections with Mongoose via Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a long running Nodejs app which uses Mongoose to connect to Mongodb. As I understand, connection pooling is turned on by default on Mongoose, and we use only a single connection within our code which we pass to all the models.

What I am confused about is when I go to the mongodb logs i see entries giving the something like the following Connection 9491 - Connections Open 53, indicating a high connection churn.  It seems as if there are connections that are being closed and reopened, although total open connections at any one time are not over the 50's range.

Our deployment architecutre was to a single instance, but now we are working with a replica set and need a high number of concurrent users to be able to access the app.

My question is why are there so many connections being opened and closed if I am connecting through Mongoose which uses connection pooling and what are the optimal settings I should use. I know connectionTimeoutMS=30000, socketConnectionTimeoutMS=30000 are recommended settings, but I'm not sure about the keepAlive, mongoose recommends 120, but by default its 1, neither of which should cause the connection churn I am seeing.

Comment: i'v the same problem too, do u have a solution today ?